# Why Android Marshmallow requires GPS to find iBeacons.?

Tags: android, gps, android-6.0-marshmallow, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I developed an app that work with iBeacons and this week i update it to work on Marshmallow. Until the update it didn't require GPS, but after the update it says that to find beacons in background it need gps. i don't find any reference on it. does someone know why Android Marshmallow requires GPS to find iBeacons?
I use altBeacon library to locate the beacons.

edit:
I'll clarify the question. Is the GPS involved in finding Beacons. Except for the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it is not necessary to have GPS turned on or even have a device with a GPS radio to detect beacons in Android 6**.  The GPS radio, if present is not activated when scanning for Bluetooth beacons.

The confusion comes from the fact that Android 6 newly requires apps to obtain either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions to be allowed to perform bluetooth scans.   This change is simply motivated by informing users that bluetooth scanning can be used to infer their location (like with beacons).  But the need to get this permission does not mean there is any technical dependency on the GPS radio.  Consider that Android also can use WiFi access points and cell towers to infer location.

On some devices, notably the Nexus 5, there have been reports that disabling Location Services (Settings -> Location -> Off) disables the ability to scan for bluetooth devices.  It is unclear whether this is a bug in that Nexus 5 build image or a new security restriction by Android that will be followed on other models in the future.  [See here for more info.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/301)  Regardless, having the GPS radio on is not a requirement for Location Services being enabled.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) open source project.

Comment: But when i monitoring beacon (the gps is on) and then turn of the gps the monitoring stop and after 7-10 sec the beacon recognized as exit region. the device has the permissions for gps its just turn off

Comment: See my revised answer with info about the Location Services dependency on some devices.  Do you actually see ranging stop working when GPS itself is turned off, or when location is turned off?

Comment: i'm sorry i had a mistake.  After turn off the gps monitoring wont stop. it continue monitoring and return regions but for some reason it wont find beacons. And yes i also work on Nexus 5.

Comment: What *exactly* do you turn off on the Nexus 5 that causes the Android Beacon Library to stop finding beacons?  Is it the overall "location" setting?  If so, understand this turns off a lot more than GPS.  To just disable GPS, select Settings -> Location -> Mode -> Battery Saving

Comment: i turn off location completely from shortcut drawer setting. disable it from battery saving its an option. But my product sell marketing are bragging all about it we don't use gps chip. therefor i don't want any reminder for gps.

Answer (score 2):

from http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via
>   Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions:

It's not GPS as such that it needs, but because beacons are a technology that can also pin point your location, the location permission is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permissions issue. iBeacon uses BT Low Energy, and in Android 6, you need location permission to initiate a scan:

> *To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions*

Source: [Android 6.0 changes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

Comment: Yes i read it too. But how the gps involve in bluetooth scans.